# How do I redirect once the correct password is entered?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to redirect the page once the password is entered and update the textbox "status".

```html
        <input type="password" id="pwd">
        <button onclick="checkPwd">Enter</button>
        <p id="status">enter password</p>
        <script>
          function checkPwd() {
            var x = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
            if (x == wideneck){
              document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "redirecting...";
              location.replace ("google.com");
            }
            else {
              document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "wrong password";
            }
          }
        </script>
```

It does not redirect or update the text box "status".

**Note: I'm not trying to make this secure, I'm just doing an experiment.**

Comment: Have you verified that the method is being called?

Comment: wideneck is not defined. You should have errors on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors on you code:

1- You dont correctly call your funtion on your button click. Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).

2- If [wideneck] is an string, you should declare it as an string: ['wideneck'] or ["wideneck"]

```html
        <input type="password" id="pwd">
        <button onclick="checkPwd()">Enter</button>
        <p id="status">enter password</p>
        <script>
          function checkPwd() {
            var x = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
            if (x == 'wideneck'){
              document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "redirecting...";
              location.replace ("google.com");
            }
            else {
              document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "wrong password";
            }
          }
        </script>
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation along with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your function is being called. Try adding parenthesis:

```
<button onclick="checkPwd()">Enter</button>
```

Comment: This fixes the calling error, but doesn't address the wideneck issue others have pointed out.